# Access feed items based on Topic

Tags: chatter, topics

I need to access feed items based on Topic. As in salesforce chatter we post feed, with that we can add #Topic to the feed. There is a field called "ParentId" on Feeditem which is reference to many objects including "Topic" object. But if I am querying as follows I am not getting any result.

SELECT TYPEOF Parent WHEN Topic THEN Id,Name ELSE Name,Id END FROM FeedItem where ParentId = '0TO90000000TzS9GAK'

instead of there is a feed item with Topic(Id = 0TO90000000TzS9GAK).

Answer (score 0):

Topics and Feed-Item are tagged in Topic-Assignment Object. You can query on this Object to get the Mapping of the related Feed-Item with Topics.

Thanks
Gautam